# Not close jQuery popUp window with asp.net button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

My popup closes when I click in send button but I need this window to stay open .. please if you can help me - thanks!

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication23.WebForm1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title></title>
        <link type="text/css" href="css-js/StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="NewFolder1/Style.css" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="css-js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="css-js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="css-js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="NewFolder1/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="NewFolder1/custom.js"></script>

        <script>       
        $("document").ready(function()
           {
               $("#thumb").click(function () {
                   $("#ovelay").fadeIn("slow");
                   $("#overlay_div").fadeIn("slow");
               });

               $(".close_button").click(function () {
                   $("#overlay").fadeOut("fast");
                   $("#overlay_div").fadeOut("fast");
               })

        });
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="css-js/validate.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <img src="css-js/66.jpg" alt="" id="thumb"/></div>
           />
    <div id ="overlay">
    </div>
    <div id = "overlay_div" style="background-color:#B5E655;opacity: 0.83;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity = 67);
    /*-ms-filter must come before filter*/
    filter: alpha(opacity = 67);
    /*INNER ELEMENTS MUST NOT BREAK THIS ELEMENTS BOUNDARIES*/
    /*All filters must be placed together*">

        <div>
          <div id="container" style="margin-top:30px ; margin-left:0px"">
          <h1> &nbsp;Contact Me</h1>
          <form id="contact_form" runat="server">
              <div>
                  <label for="name" >Name</label>
                  <input id="name" type="text" />
                  <span id="nameinfo">what's your name?</span>
              </div>

              <div>
              <label for="pass2">Téléphone</label>
              <input id="pass2" name="pass2" type="password" />
                  <span id="pass2info"></span>
                  </div>
              <div>
              <div>
                  <label for="email">E-mail</label>
                  <input id="email" name="email" type="text" />
                  <span id="emailinfo">so i can get back to you</span>
              </div>

              <label for="message">what's wanna tell me?</label>
              <textarea id="message" name="message" > </textarea>

              </div>
              <div>
         <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="send"   OnClick="send_Click"  ValidateRequestMode="Enabled" />   

              </div>
          </form>
      </div>

        </div>

        <!-- a problem is here -->

        <div id = "close_button" class= "close_button"> X </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to submit your form and to remain in the same page, you should submit the information through AJAX.

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $.ajax({ method: 'POST', data: $('#contact_form').serialize()})
        .done(function() {
              //Successful AJAX call callback
              });
   });
```

If you intend on using the submit button, you must prevent it from sending the data through the conventional method.

```
$('button').on('click', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault(); //Prevents data submission
});
```

Comment: don't work  bro whene i click in Button1 the popup close .. please if you have another solution

Comment: The only other thing I could think of is that inside your send_Click function it closes the "popup". You also have multiple insertions of the same JS File.  <script type="text/javascript" src="css-js/validate.js"></script>

Comment: i delete the others files js in my code but the problem exist again ... :/